# Как не допустить смещения центра при повороте картинки в bash?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, imagemagick

Использую imagemagick команду convert. 
проблема, что когда я объединяю картинки, созданные с помощью этой же команды поворотом, в гифку, то центр у повернутой картинки смещается... 
Как это исправить?
Вот такой командой получаю повернутую картинку
    `convert -rotate "$2" "$1" tmp.jpg`

Такой командой объединяю в гифку:
    `convert -delay 150 *.jpg "$3".gif`

Отвечу подробнее, если будет нужна еще какая-то информация.
Очень надеюсь на скорый ответ!

Comment: Вам нужно каждую картинку поместить в квадрат со стороной, равной длине диагонали изначального полотна. Тогда при объединении центровка сохраниться (+- 1 пиксель).

Comment: Спасибо! А моли бы Вы написать команду, с помощью которой можно это сделать?