# Необходимо сделать анимацию поворота картинки относительно центра в bash через imagemagick

Tags: bash, imagemagick

Есть вход вида program_name.sh **ANGLE TIME SOURCE OUT**
(гарантируется правильность ввода данных)
Необходимо из картинки **SOURCE** сделать GIF-изображение, которое будет поворачиваться на **ANGL**E градусов в течение **TIME** времени с помощью imagemagick...и сохранить в **OUT.GIF**, подскажите, как это реализовать.

Comment: выражайтесь, пожалуйста, яснее: вам ведь не «поворот картинки» надо сделать, а анимацию. для правки текста вопроса: [edit]

Comment: Уже было это задание здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739478/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-bash